# Read data from stream without blocking next reads

Tags: c#, .net, networking

In my "video chat" I transfer picture, voice and text from client to server. My problem is that I can't read incoming text while reading a picture. The picture transfer must be finished so the text transfer can begin.

Do I have to create a new connection to read at the same time when another read is running?

Comment: What technology/protocol/library are you using? C# is very broad.

Comment: @Ilya: thanks for reminding; I use `TcpClient` and reading/writing using `NetworkStream`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is enough information. I believe it will help people answer you if you elaborate more: what's the problem, in which way is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends how you do it. You *could* design a protocol which would allow the interleaving of two logical streams... but it would be cumbersome for both reading and writing... and you'd still have a problem if you wanted to read one stream while the other end was only sending a different one. Again, you could have signalling mechanisms so that each end could signal what they'd ideally like to send/receive next - but that makes things even more complicated.

Fundamentally, if you've got two streams of data it makes sense to use two connections.